# Syntax Error or Access Violation

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I am hoping this is a simple problem. I have Drupal 7.12 and MySQL 5.1.61 running on CentOS 6. I get the following error upon saving an article with Taxonomy. Has anyone run into this problem? I am hoping it is fairly simple to fix. The only Drupal module I've added is LDAP.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near '))' at line 2: SELECT base.tid AS tid, base.vid AS vid, 
base.name AS name, base.description AS description,base.format 
AS format, base.weight AS weight, v.machine_name 
AS vocabulary_machine_name FROM {taxonomy_term_data} base 
INNER JOIN {taxonomy_vocabulary} v ON base.vid = v.vid WHERE 
(base.name LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\\')
AND (base.vid IN ()) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => Exxon )
in DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (line 196 of /var/www/html/includes/entity.inc).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [Drupal core issue](http://drupal.org/node/1228076) shows, this error has made an appearance from time to time. From a reading of the thread, it looks like it is often related to a content type that is referencing a missing taxonomy vocabulary. I recommend checking your vocabularies against your content types to make sure everything is correct and consistent.

Comment: Yeah, `base.vid IN ())` at the end suggests just that.